# initializing aggregated members of a class

Tags: c++

I want to be able to initialize Seat inside of my method. I think I need to overload my '=' operator, but i am not sure.

```
void Ticket::setSize(Ticket ticket[], int a) {
   ticket[ticketCount].groupSize = a;
   ticket[ticketCount].seatInfo = new Seat[ticket[ticketCount].groupSize];
}
```

This is my Ticket class below. I am calling setSize. and passing variables to initialize seatInfo in regards to the Ticket.groupSize. below are my Ticket and seat class

```
class Ticket {
    private:
        Seat * seatInfo;
    double totalPrice;
    string flightInfo;
    int ticketNumber;
    int groupSize;

    void countPrice();
    public:
        Ticket(Seat[], int, string);

    ~Ticket();
    void print();
    double getPrice();
    string toString();
    static int getTicketCount();
    static void setTicket(Ticket[], int);
    static void setSize(Ticket[], int);
    const Seat & setSeat(Seat * );
    Seat & operator = (Seat & );
}

#endif
```

Seat.h

```
class Seat {
   private:
      int seatNumber;
   double price;
   const double BUSINESS_PRICE = 200.00;
   const double ECONOMIC_PRICE = 100.00;
   Person * reserver;

   bool isBusinessClass(int);

   public:
       // constructor
      Seat();
   Seat(int, int, Person * );
   Seat(int, double, Person * );
}
```

Errors I'm getting are no constructor that can do it. and no '=' operator function. If you need more info please let me know

Answer (score 0):

seatInfo is defined as a pointer of Seat.

Seat *seatInfo;

ticket[ticketCount].seatInfo can be a pointer to a Seat instance but not an array of Seat instances.

What about letting seatInfo point to 1 instance of Seat to see if the errors are still there?

ticket[ticketCount].seatInfo = new Seat();

Answer (score 0):

Constuctors are called as `new Class()`, in your case `new Seat()`. So replace the [] after `new Seat` with (). Also, you are trying to call the constructor `Seat(int)`, which is not declared, so either use one of the 3 you declared or declare it.